# if values in common column in two data frame match- i would like to sum values in other columns, otherwise merge remaining rows

Tags: merge, sum, match

I have two dataframes:

Dataframe 1: df1

| Identifier | Count |

1. A|B      | 2     |
2. C|D      | 3     |

Dataframe 2: df2

| Identifier | Count |

1. A|B      |   1   |
2. E|F      |   4   |

I want:

df3:

| Identifier  | Count  |

1. A|B        |  3     |
2. C|D        |  3     |
3. E|F        |  4     |

I have tried

```
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

but this returns rows one below the other doesn't add count if identifiers are matching.

I also tried

```
df3<- data.frame(merge(x=df1, y=df2, by=c("Identifier"), all = TRUE)
```

but I get a lot of extra columns in my dataset which I don't want